# How to find $P(|W| < 1)$?

Tags: probability

I know that: $Z$~$N(0, 1^2)$, $Y$~$B(3, \frac{1}{2})$, $X$~$B(1, \frac{1}{3})$

$W = XY + (1-X)Z$

And I need to calculate $P(|W| < 1)$.

I know that $(1 -X)$ cannot be negative so I'm trying somehow to get rid of the abs sign. Maybe $Z$ cannot be negative as well?

Comment: $Z$ **definitely** can be negative. Say, half the time.

Comment: Ok so can I get directions?

Comment: Do you know how to compute $\mathbb{P}\{ \lvert Z\rvert  < 1\}$ and $\mathbb{P}\{ Y  < 1\}$? If so, conditional probabilities (conditioning on $X$) will help.

Comment: Solved. Thanks!

Comment: Great --- you're welcome!